# What is the difference between next() and nextTag() in XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, xml, tags, xmlpullparser

I understand that nextTag() goes to the next tag,which can be start or end tag. What about next()? Does it go to the next text/tag depending on what it is?

For example, if we have the xml:

```
<summary type="html">
            <p>I have an Application that requires a data file...</p>

</summary>
```

Assuming that the parser is currently at summary start tag, does doing a next() move to the p tag or the text immediately after that?I looked at a code from Google site and it does this:

```
private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "summary");
    String summary = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "summary");
    return summary;
}

// For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It only calls 1 next() starting from the summary tag and extracts the text from it. Shouldn't it call next() twice to get to the text,cause doing so once only reaches the p tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**What is the difference between next() and nextTag():**

Suppose you have written some codes inside the `next()` method. When `nextTag()` method gets executed it calls the **`next()`** method at first then if the element contains **START_TAG** or **END_TAG** then it return the appropriate event otherwise it throughs an exception.

**FROM OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION:**

**`next()`**

*Get next parsing event - element content will be coalesced and only one TEXT event must be returned for whole element content (comments and processing instructions will be ignored and entity references must be expanded or exception mus be thrown if entity reference can not be expanded).*

**`nextTag()`**

*Call next() and return event if it is START_TAG or END_TAG otherwise throw an exception.*

Comment: Hi, so in this case, after calling next() the next element should be the p tag?(starting from the summary tag)?

Comment: Actually, if you have 3 consecutive <p></p> <p></p> <p></p> inside of the <summary> tag. Then next() will take you to the next <p> tag. And when you reach to last one then it will not take you to some where else rather throughs an exception